# Populate comboBox in flex 4 using remote Object

Tags: apache-flex

I have a remote object returned and I am trying to populate it into combobox.

```
<s:RemoteObject id="ro" result="result(event)" destination="echoServiceDestination">

private var statesData:ArrayCollection;

private function result(e:ResultEvent):void{
   statesData = e.result as  ArrayCollection;

}
```

How can I turn this collection into something like {label:"Red", data:"#FF0000"} so that I can populate into combobox

The remote object is party and I can't seem to able to cast it as below

```
                  var party:Party = new Party;

            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < statesData.length; i++)
            {
                party = statesData.getItemAt(i);    

            }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the format of your data being returned?  Your Code sample doesn't include any code to cast the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a label function. Set the returning data directly as dataprovider to your combobox:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="comboBox"

            dataProvider="{statesData}"
            labelFunction="labelFunc" />
```

This will be your label function:

```
        private function labelFunc(item:Object):String {
            return item.label; // Or whatever parameter you want to display
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use this method, how do I pass in the id/data to be submit to backend. Now it display the label only.

Comment: Labelfuntion is for display purpose only. If you get the selected value from the combobox you will have the  entire object, not just the label (or whatever field you chose for display).

Comment: Hi, I manage to get id by using the change event on the combo box and casting to the object.                    protected function primaryParty_changeHandler(event:ListEvent):void
{
var tempParty:Party = primaryParty.selectedItem as Party;
}

Comment: Another option would be to use the labelField property instead of the labelFunction property. You can specify the field directly.